# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'null, *', but only one is allowed

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, request

Here is my code

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {

    var responseText = xmlhttp.status + xmlhttp.responseText; 
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=responseText;   
  }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","https://exmaple.com/public/onDemandDemo/Products?$top=2");");
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

when I tried to perform GET request I am getting
**

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://https://exmaple.com/public/onDemandDemo/Products?$top=2.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'null, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'null' is therefore not
>   allowed access."

** error

But I am getting response when I used same url and header in requestmaker.com

please help as I am very new to javascript and AJAX.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: In what browser do you get this error? What headers are really sent?

Comment: I am using chrome, while debugging I got that error. I tried in other browsers also.

Comment: Same thing i did it in android there it is working. Am I correctly sending the request??

Comment: [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a CORS response header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/710446) sent by a server. It seems like the server you're contacting is sending multiple comma-separated values in their `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response, which your browser doesn't like. Other browser might tolerate this; you have found at least one browser that does not.